# how can i get static field in JSP file?

Tags: java, jsp

i set a static field in jsp page `a.jsp`:

```
<%!
public static int A=123;
%>
```

how can i get this static variable `A` in other JSP file? (do not include `a.jsp`)

it is possible?

thanks for help :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't do this. Put the variable into a larger<sup>†</sup> scope, either `request`, `session`, or `application` scope. Using JSTL (because scriptlets are generally bad practice):

```
<c:set var="A" value="${123}" scope="application" />
```

[More on scoped variables](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0211.html#N10100).

---

<sub><sup>†</sup>By "larger," I mean "larger than `page`" scope. Page scope is the default for variables created using `<c:set/>`, e.g. when no scope is specified.</sub>

Comment: Beat me to it -- I was just in the process of typing the same thing.  This is the correct way to do it.

Comment: thanks, i add `<c:set var="A" value="${123}" scope="application" />` in a.jsp,I can get variable `A` in a.jsp,but I can't get `A` in b.jsp,why? (must include <c:set ...` in every jsp page,or inlcude it?)

Comment: @Zenofo: you have access `a.jsp` in order to create the value, _before_ to try to access `b.jsp`.

Comment: @Zenofo:  you might want to include a brief explanation of what you are trying to actually accomplish in your project.